# Not getting result output table of MSSQL stored procedure in python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, csv, pymssql

My python code is based on:

1. Importing a CSV file in Python
2. Connecting to SQL Server Database
3. Query 1 in python- insert statement which inserts the value in table1 from csv file
4. Query 2 in python- executing stored procedure 1  which is a 'select statement'
5. Query 3 in python- executing stored procedure 2 which is a 'update statement for table1'
6. Query 4 in python- executing stored procedure 3 which is a 'select statement which has several table joins on table1 and producing a result with 8 columns'
7. Exporting the result to a new csv file

The whole python code gets executed successfully executed but produces a blank csv file but and don't get any output from the cursor for query 4.

---

My sample code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 
import csv
cnxn_1 = pyodbc.connect()
with open("""csv path""") as csv1:
     reader = csv.reader(csv)
     cursor_1 = cnxn_1.cursor()
     cursor_1.execute("""INSERT INTO TABLE1""")
     cursor_1.commit()
cnxn_1.close()   

cnxn_2 = pyodbc.connect()  
cursor_2 = cnxn_2.cursor()
cursor_2.execute("""exec stored_proc_select_statement @parameter""")
result_1 = cursor_2.fetchall()
print (result_1)
cnxn_2.close()

cnxn_3 = pyodbc.connect() 
cursor_3 = cnxn_3.cursor()
cursor_3.execute("""exec stored_proc_update_statement @parameter""")
cursor_3.commit()
cnxn_3.close()

cnxn_4 = pyodbc.connect() 
cursor_4 = cnxn_4.cursor()
cursor_4.execute("""exec stored_proc_final_select_statement @parameter""")
cursor_4.commit()
cnxn_4.close()
result_2 = cursor_4.fetchall()
print (result_1)
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor_4.description]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result_2, columns=columns)
print(df)
df.to_csv("""new csv path""")
cnxn_4.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You close Connection 4 prematurely:

```
cnxn_4 = pyodbc.connect() 
cursor_4 = cnxn_4.cursor()
cursor_4.execute("""exec stored_proc_final_select_statement @parameter""")
cursor_4.commit()
# **cnxn_4.close()**  ## Comment this out, or remove it.
result_2 = cursor_4.fetchall()
print (result_1)
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor_4.description]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result_2, columns=columns)
print(df)
df.to_csv("""new csv path""")
cnxn_4.close()
```